# mongodb bulk records exists validation in spring data

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Given a List of mongo document UUIDs, I would like to validate if these IDs have corresponding documents in the DB. What is the efficient way to perform bulk validation?
Lets say my program has 100 id strings and would like to validate all these IDs in one DB call. Is it feasible?
I could do it sequentially (i.e using `exists(T id)` methods in spring data repository) but I would rather want to do in one call.

My program uses spring data for  mongodb. But I am open to any native mongo command. I can code the Query in spring data for it. Also, If any of the ID in the list does not have a document in DB, I want to get such ID in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know spring-data but you can use the [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator and do something like `find({ _id : { $in : [ your, ids, here ] } })` and then work from there.  If you need a simple yes/no for all of them existing, you can just check the length of your result set vs. the length of your input array.

Comment: Thanks. Does this also give me the list of Ids that do not have matching documents? or any way to configure it to get me such list.

Comment: I would recommend doing a set substraction on the fetched _ids against the ones you're querying.  I don't think know off hand how to do what you want in mongo directly.  If you're only querying 100 items or so, your application code should be able to do the diff easy enough.